# mysql query join three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
players
------
id|name 

teams
-------
id|name 

teams_players
-------------
id|teamID|playerID
```

I now want to get every entry from table "players" where players.id is for example in the team with id 15. With other words: I want to get every player that belongs to a specific team (e.g teamID=15)

I tried a join but it fails.

Here is what i got so far:

```
       "SELECT players.*
        FROM players
        JOIN teams_players
        ON teams_players.teamID = 15 
        GROUP BY players.id";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are way overcomplicating this.

```
select players.*
 from players
 join teams_players
 on players.id = teams_players.playerid
 where teams_players.teamid = 15
```

The `JOIN` part has nothing to do with the number 15. The 15 is how you filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

you can join your table with more than  one conditions also you haven't mention the relation between your tables in the `on` clause

```
SELECT players.*
        FROM players
        JOIN teams_players
        ON (players.id = teams_players.playerid AND teams_players.teamID = 15 )
        GROUP BY players.id
```